# Can I force OSX to keep an app in RAM?

Tags: macos, memory, emacs

I use Emacs and want it to be super-snappy whenever I switch to it to perform an operation. Unfortunately, often I will switch to it and a noticeable delay occurs after the first keystroke. I'm guessing that this is due to the Emacs process being swapped out to disk.

I have seen that there are guides to turn off swap in OSX. I do not want to do this. How can I force OSX to keep just one app in RAM at all times?

Edit to answer some questions in the comments:

- I'm running the latest version of Yosemite (10.10.4) on a 2015 Macbook Air
- I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 (installed through Homebrew)
- It's not very practical to test with `emacs -Q` as that would omit many of the packages where the lag is most noticeable. For example: `helm` with a number of file sources, `helm-M-x` and custom Org agendas.
- The delay, when I notice it, is around 1 second long. At other times (when I am working in the app for longer periods of time) the delay is less than 0.25 seconds for the above commands.

Comment: Turning off swap would only make things worse. With no ability to swap, it would have no choice but to discard clean pages, such as the ones holding the application.

Comment: Does this happen with **Emacs -Q**?  Are you using the most recent stable release of the Vanilla/Generic build for OSX?  Your problem doesn't sound like the *norm* for the Emacs experience.  Are we talking 1/4 second, 1/2 second, 1 second . . .?

Comment: Also - which OS X? Yosemite is far better than Mavericks at doing that - but both are considerably happier & snappier booted from an SSD these days. Mavericks with full-ish RAM & HD will give precisely that symptom at the slightest provocation, even if it claims not to be actually paging.